# Better tool than responsive.is

Tags: responsive-design

[Responsive.is](http://responsive.is/) is an awesome website to preview any site in different browser sizes and orientations.
Is there a similar tool that also supports mini-tablets?

Comment: They support tablets and smart phones is that not enough?

Comment: mini tablets would be a great option. Also, when you look at a site in the smartphone size you can't scroll it all the way up

Comment: Most sites which don't have a separate mobile version of their domain usually use CSS to change styles based on the browser size. You can just change the size of your browser and view how a site responds to different sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [responsivepx by Remy Sharp](http://responsivepx.com/), which lets you control the precise width instead of providing fixed device widths.

Answer (score 9):

Since Firefox 15, you have a built in reponsive design tool integrated and accessible from the web developper menu.

[image]

See [this blog post](http://paulrouget.com/e/devtoolsupdate/) from Paul Rouget.

Comment: Firefox's responsive design tool is mostly unusable for tablet and mobile device previewing - because it scales down to 320px *excluding* the scroll-bar width - leaving you with <320px wide document. Configurability or a simple checkbox that includes/excludes the scrollbar would make it much better.

Comment: nonetheless, this tool is far superior to any of the `<iframe>` hacks out there - which don't work for any self-respecing sites that disallow framing (essential to prevent click-jacking attacks)

Answer (score 4):

I came across [screenqueri.es](http://screenqueri.es/) today. It allows to select specific phones or tables, for example a 7" Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score 1):

[jResize](http://www.toddmotto.com/jresize-plugin-for-one-window-responsive-development) is a jQuery plugin that does basically the same thing as the responsive.is site, except you now have full control over the specified dimensions.

Since you load it directly on your own domain, you're not dependent on someone else's uptime, it'll still work if your site's not public(eg. behind htaccess auth), and your clients can also use it without navigating unfamiliar menus.

Answer (score 0):

I use a several different websites to check out my responsive designs. I have links to 5 at http://reactivewebdesign.net/Resourses/Links - I just started using jResize and find it has some nice features.